# Question about Iaijutsu organisation within the US

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I wonder why [this question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/923/82) has not been closed on the ground that it is too localised.

Would the same question if it were looking for an organisation within Mongolia be left open?

Comment: Alas, I tried. :)

Answer (score 4):

The meat of the question is:

> Is there a central body/organization in the US that focuses, at least
>   in part, on promotion of Iaijutsu in the US?

I don't see this as something that is *too* localized since the asker is looking for a general organization that is functioning within the large geographical boundaries of the United States. Though the asker provides the context of his question as finding an instructor, I am reading this question as a platform to go and find that information from another resource. That type of question could benefit others who are seeking the same thing.

Stslavik left a [comment](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/923/is-there-a-us-based-organization-supporting-iaijutsu#comment1503_923) on this question as well.

> Sounds like a reasonable question, so long as we're sticking with the
>   existence of organizations in the US for iaijutsu; if we start getting
>   into individual instructors, that's off topic for this site.

If the question were too granular, e.g. asking about a very specific (and unknown) location or instructor, then it would be too localized.